# Opening links in a frame target IE10 Start app for Windows 8

Tags: hyperlink, frame, target, internet-explorer-10

I have a page being showed in two frames

```
<frameset cols="140,*">
    <frame src="resources/nav-bar.html" id="nav-bar" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
    <frame src="resources/home.html" id="main" frameborder=0 scrolling="yes" noresize="noresize" />
</frameset>
```

Then in the frame named *nav-bar* I have links targeted to *main* like this:

```
<a href="personal_details.html" target="main">Personal details</a>
```

In Google Chrome and Safari this works with no issues but IE10 for Windows 8 when run from the Start opens the link in a new tab instead. Nevertheless if I run IE10 from the desktop I have no such issue. How can this be fixed? Thanks in advance.

EMILIO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sad little problem and apparently Microsoft is aware of it. (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793437, for example.) What makes it even sadder is it seems to only appear on Windows 8, IE10 running on Windows 7 does not exhibit this problem. I manage to solve it by replacing the markup for the page I am using to navigate around, in your example the *resources/nav-bar.html* file. I changed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Blah blah</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./some.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
...
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Blah blah</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./some.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
...
```

Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Try using property name.

```
name="main"
```

Comment: Hi! First of all thank you for your answer. I wasn't sure if I was supposed to try the property in an <i>a</i> tag or in the frames tags so I tried in both unsuccessfully. However I did realize something: it doesn't work on the Start app for Windows 8 but I have no issues while running it on the desktop IE10. I will correct the question and edit to make sure this information is clear.

Comment: I don´t have w8 to help you with this, but I think frames could have been deprecated. You could try to use divs instead, with javascript and innerHTML. I can post an example.